# Find who will change a record in oracle DB

Tags: oracle-10g

Someone is updating a record in a custom Oracle table, is there a way to find who is updating the record and or at least the table?

Answer (score 2):

You can audit updates to the table (assuming that auditing is enabled in your database).  Or you can create a trigger on the table that captures the user and the row being updated and writes the results to an audit table.  Or you can use the `DBMS_LOGMNR` package to go through the historical redo logs to see who executed an `UPDATE` in the past.

In any of these cases, you'll see the Oracle user that did the `UPDATE`.  That may or may not be what you want, however.  Most applications these days are three-tier applications where the user that is connecting to the database is shared by many different human users.  If your middle tier is handling the process of authenticating users and using a single shared Oracle user account in its connection pools, you would need to have the middle tier record who is doing the `UPDATE` or you would need for the middle tier to identify to the database who the current application user is for any request via a context, via calls to `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`, via calls to a stored procedure, or by just passing the user in with the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: It is being done, directly on the table, by Toad or SQL plus and I do not have access to create triggers.

Comment: @Kiranshell - If you don't have access to create triggers, does that imply that you also don't have access to enable and configure auditing and that you don't have access to the historical redo logs?  If you just have privileges to query the data, you can't get privileges to be able to record who is updating rows, and the people that do have those privileges aren't able to help you, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: can we use V$SESSION_LONGOPS, if we know to what value it is being updated using sql.

Comment: @Kiranshell - Why would you use that?  A simple update will not generally cause an entry in `V$SESSION_LONGOPS` because it is not a long operation.  There is some chance that you could actively monitor `V$SQL` and `V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE` and, if you got really lucky, find the session and thus the user that was executing a particular `UPDATE` statement with a particular bind variable value.  But that would generally require quite a bit of luck or quite a bit of patience until you happened to see the particular activity that you're looking for.

Comment: I know the exact Id, which is unique for each record, that will be used in the sql.

Comment: @Kiranshell - So, you know that someone is going to issue an `UPDATE` in the future, you know the primary key that they are going to update, but you don't know who is going to do the update?  That seems rather odd-- can you give a bit more context?  If the `UPDATE` is being issued from SQL*Plus, I assume it's a one-time event, not a constant process.  Is the `UPDATE` statement using bind variables?

Comment: Yes it is a one time event, and the update statement probably has the primary key in bind variable.

Comment: @Kiranshell - If you don't have permissions to create triggers, audit changes, or view redo log data and the person doing the update is using bind variables and is only going to issue the `UPDATE` once, you're probably out of luck.  There is a small chance that you might get extremely lucky and `v$sql_bind_capture` will happen to capture the bind variable value you care about at the instant the user issues this query and that you'll happen to query the table at exactly the right time.  But that's a hugely unlikely sequence of events

Comment: but I heard that bind variables of all queries will be stored for few days.

Comment: @Kiranshell - Some small percentage of bind variables will be captured, a smaller percentage will be saved into the AWR tables for a few days depending on your AWR settings.  It's possible that you'd get lucky but highly unlikely.

Comment: oh got luck, I think I see the SQL in v$sql, but the sql_text is only partial, how can I see the full query and will I be able to use the SQL hash and find the bind variables?

Comment: @Kiranshell - `sql_fulltext` is the full text of the SQL statement.  You probably can't get the bind variable values.  If Oracle happened to capture the bind variable values for a particular execution, that would be in `v$sql_bind_capture` (which you join to from `v$sql` using the `sql_id` column).  The vast majority of the time, though, bind variable values will never be captured.  Some fraction of the bind variable values that are captured will be stored in `DBA_HIST_SQLBIND` for however long AWR retains data.

Comment: will all the sqls run in past 1 hours be captured in v$sql?

Comment: @Kiranshell - Likely but not guaranteed depending on how quickly your system happens to purge statements from the shared pool.  There is also no guarantee that you will be able to determine who executed a particular query that you find in `v$sql`.  You can determine the original parsing user but many other users might have executed the statement since it was parsed.